# Understanding of Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $F$ ⊆ $K$ fields and $F$ is a subfield of $K$. Then $K$ is a vector space over $F$.

My question is that why $K$ is a vector space over $F$? I did not understand really.

Comment: It satisfies the axioms of vector space, where $(K,+)$ is the usual additive structure, while $\cdot :F \times K \to K$ is the usual multiplication.

Comment: @Crostul Then, can be every field a vector space over F? (F is a field)

Comment: @hayyam answer this: why *can't* $\Bbb Q$ be a vector space over $\Bbb R$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom $\mathbb{Q}$ can't be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ since $\mathbb{R}$ $\not\subseteq$ $\mathbb{Q}$. So, I found the answer of my question.